# How to find out Out Of Office flag from a mail header using C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

How do I find out "Out Of Office" flag from a received email using C#.

I dont have any scope to parse the Subject / Body. I need to find only thru either the header property if available. Or any other means.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1):

You can add the custom header to the mailMessage as below,

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To = "me@mycompany.com";
mail.From = "you@yourcompany.com";
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body.";
mail.Headers.Add( "X-Organization", "My Company LLC" );//Your custom header goes here
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";  //your real server goes here
SmtpMail.Send( mail );
```

and letter you can access it as below,

```
 IEnumerable<string> headerValues = mail.Headers.GetValues("X-Organization");
 var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I don't see the "MyCustomID" value in your message sending example. Should it be placed instead of "X-Organization"?

Comment: Can you describe how does **X-Organization** & **My Computer LLC** help in getting Out Of Office reply?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Outlook Object Model, check if the MailItem.MessageClass property is "IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft". This will only work if the sender is in the same domain as the receiver. Otherwise all bets are off - this is nothing special about the OOF messages.